# Why is Visual Studio stopping and restarting?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

Recently I have become very fed up with my MSV4 code. I have many forms in my project and every form is doing fine, but one of the controller actions is annoying me. When I try to debug this code, Visual Studio stops and restarts.

I don't know what is happening.

**CODE:**

```
  public ActionResult stockMaster(tbl_stockMaster ts)
        {
            try {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    string vl = ts.orderNo;
                    //Record record = data.Records.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id == id);
                   // var org1 = db.tbl_stockMaster.SingleOrDefault(vno => vno.orderNo == ts.orderNo);
                    var org1 = db.tbl_stockMaster.FirstOrDefault(q => q.orderNo.Equals(vl));
                    if (org1 != null)
                    {
                         db.SaveChanges();
                        return Json(new{ id=org1.id}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ts.userinfo = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
                        db.tbl_stockMaster.Add(ts);
                        object obj = db.SaveChanges();
                        int id = ts.id;
                        TempData["fk"] = id;
                        return Json(new { id = id },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                }
                return Json(new { msg = "Model is Not Valid" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                return Json(new { msg = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

        }
```

Mainly problems occur when it tries to run this line:

```
var org1 = db.tbl_stockMaster.FirstOrDefault(q => q.orderNo.Equals(vl));
```

I have tried a lot to find out the solutions to this problem, but i cannot find any. Please help me some solutions.

Comment: Sounds like a slow database query where it should be relatively fast. Does that table have a lot of data / well indexed / network latency / etc?

Comment: what is the error you get when visual studio crashes? there isn't any information here that we can use to solve this issue for you, and your emotional response to the issue isn't relevant.

Comment: [C# Linq FirstOrDefault](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/linq/E23I160714-Understanding-Single,-SingleOrDefault,-First-and-FirstOrDefault.html)

Comment: It is showing a message is visual studio has stopped working

Comment: dig deeper.  There is an option to view more info, or get the info on the module that crashed from the event viewer in windows.

Comment: run visual studio with logging enabled - i.e.: Devenv.exe /log <log path>

Comment: or you can check you window error logs, there should be something there

Comment: Try refreshing your db model and make sure EF is not corrupt for some reason. I had a similar issue, mine was because some weird issue with EF. I updated EF and it started working..

Comment: I have found new clue that if the value org1=null then the code is running fine otherwise it is going to crash. Is there any option for value searching into database.